# Alternatives to Google's UTM tags?

Tags: url, html-email, tracking, utm

I'm looking for a simple way of tracking link clicks (sent via e-mail) to an outside url. Google's UTM tags look like the perfect solution, but instead of sending the information to GA, I want it to send to my servers.

Is there a way to do this? The only viable options I've seen so far are redirects (send user to my site first and then redirect them). However, I don't want to compromise the users experience.

Perhaps there are some techniques out there that someone could share with me?

Thanks